# connection not initialized issue resolved after restart iis

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, memory-leaks, application-pool

My MVC web application crashes sometimes in live server while we are working on it. All users are facing [Exceptions]yellow error screen.

[image]

This exception occurs on randomly not on specific location or specific click. But when I restart my application on IIS the application working fine. but again some hours same problem appears.

When I try to Re-login Then application don't respond. but after restart IIS. I successfully login in to application with same credentials.

Comment: Things related to SQL Server are common, but it should be your SQL Server administrators to assist such as https://sqlperformance.com/2017/07/sql-performance/find-database-connection-leaks

Comment: Actually this error occurs when server makes connection but can't build due to failure in identifying connection function identifier. This problem can be solved by typing connection function in code.  For example: `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);` Function is conn.